# Don't print the chart in pdf with phpexcel

Tags: phpexcel, jpgraph

Currently I'm making my reports with phpexcel, everythink is ok when I make the report with charts in xlsx;

> ... $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel,'Excel2007');  $objWriter->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
>   $objWriter->save('php://output'); 
>   exit;

and when I do it in html with;

> $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'HTML');
>   $objWriter->setIncludeCharts(TRUE); 
>   $objWriter->save('php://output');

But the problem is when I want to create the pdf file my response is  a pdf without charts, and yes previously I added the PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_MPDF AND PHPExcel_Settings::CHART_RENDERER_JPGRAPH;

> header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
>   $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'PDF');
>   $objWriter->setIncludeCharts(TRUE); 
>   $objWriter->save('php://output');

May be there is a problem because I save the file in the client browser?